# is it data race in nested thrust functor

Tags: cuda, gpu, thrust

I have tested this snippet and try to explain its cause as well as a way to resolve it, but have failed to do so

```
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>

#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>

struct alter_tuple {

    alter_tuple(const int& a_, const int& b_) : a(a_), b(b_){};

    __host__ __device__
    thrust::tuple<int,int> operator()(thrust::tuple<int,int> X)
    {
    int Xx = thrust::get<0>(X);
    int Xy = thrust::get<1>(X);
    int Xpx = a*Xx-b*Xy;
    int Xpy = -b*Xx+a*Xy;

    printf("in (%d,%d) -> (%d,%d)\n",Xx,Xy,Xpx,Xpy);

        return thrust::make_tuple(Xpx,Xpy);
    }

    int a;   // these variables a,b are shared between different threads used by this functor kernel
    int b;   // which easily creates racing problem
};


struct alter_tuple_arr {

    alter_tuple_arr(int* a_, int* b_, int* c_, int* d_) : a(a_), b(b_), c(c_), d(d_) {};

    __host__ __device__
    thrust::tuple<int,int> operator()(const int& idx)
    {
    int Xx = a[idx];
    int Xy = b[idx]; 
    int Xpx = a[idx]*Xx-b[idx]*Xy;
    int Xpy = -b[idx]*Xx+a[idx]*Xy;

    printf("in (%d,%d) -> (%d,%d)\n",Xx,Xy,Xpx,Xpy);

        return thrust::make_tuple(Xpx,Xpy);
    }

    int* a;
    int* b;
    int* c;
    int* d;
};


struct bFuntor 
{
    bFuntor(int* av__, int* bv__, int* cv__, int* dv__, const int& N__) : av_(av__), bv_(bv__), cv_(cv__), dv_(dv__), N_(N__) {};

    __host__ __device__
    int operator()(const int& idx)
    {
    thrust::device_ptr<int> av_dpt = thrust::device_pointer_cast(av_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> av_dpt1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(av_+N_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> bv_dpt = thrust::device_pointer_cast(bv_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> bv_dpt1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(bv_+N_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> cv_dpt = thrust::device_pointer_cast(cv_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> cv_dpt1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(cv_+N_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dv_dpt = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dv_);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dv_dpt1 = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dv_+N_);

    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> a0 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(av_dpt);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> a1 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(av_dpt1);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> b0 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(bv_dpt);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> b1 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(bv_dpt1);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> c0 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(cv_dpt);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> c1 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(cv_dpt1);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> d0 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(dv_dpt);
    thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>> d1 = thrust::detail::make_normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int>>(dv_dpt1);

    // ** alter_tuple is WRONG
#define WRONG
#ifdef WRONG
    thrust::transform(thrust::device,
              thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(a0,b0)),
              thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(a1,b1)),
//            thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(cv_dpt,dv_dpt)),   // cv_dpt  
              thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(c0,d0)),   // cv_dpt  
              alter_tuple(cv_[idx],dv_[idx]));    
#endif

#ifdef RIGHT
    // ** alter_tuple_arr is CORRECT way to do it
    thrust::transform(thrust::device,
              thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),
              thrust::counting_iterator<int>(N_),
//            thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(cv_dpt,dv_dpt)),   // cv_dpt  
              thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(c0,d0)),   // cv_dpt  
              alter_tuple_arr(av_,bv_,cv_,dv_));    
#endif

    for (int i=0; i<N_; i++)
      printf("out: (%d,%d) -> (%d,%d)\n",av_[i],bv_[i],cv_[i],dv_[i]);

        return cv_dpt[idx];
    }

    int* av_;
    int* bv_;
    int* cv_;
    int* dv_;
    int N_;
    float af;   // are these variables host side or device side??
};


__host__ __device__
unsigned int hash(unsigned int a)
{
    a = (a+0x7ed55d16) + (a<<12);
    a = (a^0xc761c23c) ^ (a>>19);
    a = (a+0x165667b1) + (a<<5);
    a = (a+0xd3a2646c) ^ (a<<9);
    a = (a+0xfd7046c5) + (a<<3);
    a = (a^0xb55a4f09) ^ (a>>16);
    return a;
}


int main(void)
{
      int N = 10;
      std::vector<int> av,bv,cv,dv;
      unsigned int seed = hash(10);
      thrust::default_random_engine rng(seed);
      thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> u01(0,10);

      for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
    av.push_back((int)u01(rng));
    bv.push_back((int)u01(rng));
    cv.push_back((int)u01(rng));
    dv.push_back((int)u01(rng));

//  printf("%d %d %d %d \n",av[i],bv[i],cv[i],dv[i]);
      }

      thrust::device_vector<int> av_d(N);
      thrust::device_vector<int> bv_d(N);
      thrust::device_vector<int> cv_d(N);
      thrust::device_vector<int> dv_d(N);
      av_d = av; bv_d = bv; cv_d = cv; dv_d = dv;

      thrust::transform(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),
            thrust::counting_iterator<int>(N),
            cv_d.begin(),
            bFuntor(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(av_d.data()), 
                  thrust::raw_pointer_cast(bv_d.data()),
                  thrust::raw_pointer_cast(cv_d.data()),
                  thrust::raw_pointer_cast(dv_d.data()),
                  N));    

      thrust::host_vector<int> bv_h(N);
      thrust::copy(bv_d.begin(), bv_d.end(), bv_h.begin());   // probably I forgot this! to copy back the result from device to host!

      return 0;
}
```

In this nested thrust calls, two nested functors were tested, one of them worked (one with "#define RIGHT"). In the case of WRONG functor i.e. alter_tuple:

- where do two variables  int a, int b reside? host or device? or local kernel registers? or they are shared between threads of this functor's operator?
- Inside, the alter_tuple functor, I tried to print out the result (int printf("in...")) and this is correct calculation. However, when this result is returned to caller functor and is printed out (in printf("out....")), they are incorrect and are different with its previous calculation

how come can these results are different? I can't seem to explain it and there is no documents or example to refer to

this difference is shown in output [here](https://pastebin.com/FSypmfs2)

**Edit 1**:

minimum size test code shows functors (literally, **a*x = y**) in both cases receive/initialize values correctly [SO_example_no_tuple_arr_wo_c.cu](https://pastebin.com/9bMLvP30)

print out is:

```
out: 9*8 -> 72
out: 9*8 -> 72
out: 9*8 -> 72
out: 6*4 -> 24
out: 6*4 -> 24
out: 6*4 -> 24
out: 1*8 -> 8
out: 1*8 -> 8
out: 1*6 -> 6
out: 9*1 -> 9
out: 9*1 -> 9
```

which shows the correct received values

minimum test code without using pointer/array to pass input values shows that regardless of input values are correctly initialized, the return results are wrong [SO_example_no_tuple.cu](https://pastebin.com/jGAv2hrr)

its output in case N=2:

```
in 9*8 -> 72
in 6*4 -> 24
in 9*8 -> 72
in 6*4 -> 24
out: 9*8 -> 24
out: 9*8 -> 24
out: 6*4 -> 24
out: 6*4 -> 24
```

Comment: There are no data races here. This is a design problem

Comment: @talonmies: how about in the nested functor and caller functor, why are the  results different? I printed them from the same variables

Comment: is there a way to get consistent results when nested thrust calls are used? I tried "thrust::device" to force device execution policy but it seems not to fix. And posts elsewhere confirm that nested thrust is supported

Comment: any reference or direction I can refer to to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in values is not strictly due to a data race problem.

Your two approaches do not do the same thing, and it has to do with the values of `a` and `b` that will be selected for each invocation of the nested `thrust::transform` call.  This is evident if you set `N` = 1, which should remove any concerns about data racing.  The results are still different.

In the "failing" case, you are invoking the `alter_tuple()` operator like so:

```
thrust::transform(thrust::device,
          ...
          alter_tuple(cv_[idx],dv_[idx]));
```

These values (`cv_[idx]`, `dv_[idx]`) then become your initializing parameters ending up in `a` and `b` variables inside the functor.  But your "passing" case is effectively initializing these variables differently, using `a[idx]` and `b[idx]`, which correspond to `av_[idx]` and `bv_[idx]`.  If we change the `alter_tuple` invocation to use a and b:

```
          alter_tuple(av_[idx],bv_[idx]));
```

then the `N` = 1 case results now match.  This was easier to understand because we had in fact only one entry in the `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` vectors.

When we expand to the `N` = 10 case, however, we no longer get matching results.  To explain why, we need to understand the use of `a` and `b` inside the functor in this case.  In the "failing" case, we are passing **a single initializing value** for each of `a` and `b` as used in the functor:

```
          alter_tuple(av_[idx],bv_[idx]));
```

so, for a given thread, which means for a given invocation of the nested `thrust::transform` call, **a single value** will be used for `a` and `b`:

```
alter_tuple(const int& a_, const int& b_) : a(a_), b(b_){};
...
int a;   //   these values are constant across variation of "idx" 
int b;   //   passed to the functor
```

on the other hand, in the  "passing" case, the `a` and `b` values will vary **for each element passed to the functor**, within the nested transform call:

```
thrust::tuple<int,int> operator()(const int& idx)
{
int Xx = a[idx];  // these values of a and b *vary* for each idx
int Xy = b[idx];  // passed to the functor
```

Once that is understood, if the "passing" case is the desired case, then I have no idea how to transform the first case to produce passing results, as there is no way you can cause a *single* initializing value to take on the behavior of the varying values for `a` and `b` in the "passing" case.

None of the above involves data racing, but since your operations (i.e. each thread) is writing to every value of `c` and `d`, I don't think this overall approach makes any sense, and I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  I think if you expanded this to more elements/threads, then you could certainly experience unpredictable/variable results.

To answer some of your other questions, the variables `a` and `b` end up as thread-local variables, on the device.  So each data member in either functor is a thread-local variable on the device.

> Inside, the alter_tuple functor, I tried to print out the result (int printf("in...")) and this is correct calculation. However, when this result is returned to caller functor and is printed out (in printf("out....")), they are incorrect and are different with its previous calculation

Each thread is writing to the *same* locations in the `c` and `d` vector.  Therefore, since each thread writes to the entire vector, **but** (in the failing case) each thread uses a **different** initializing value for `a` and `b` inside the functor, it  stands to reason that each thread will compute a different result for the values of `c` and `d`, and the results you get after completion of the thrust call will depend on which thread "wins" the output write operation.  This is unpredictable, and certainly not all threads printout will match the final result, because each thread will compute different values for `c` and `d`.

Comment: @Crovella I've spent some effort to verify your explanation and made my test code much shorter, so that the cause can be easily spotted. For this explanation "a single value will be used for a and b", I printed out the according "a" and "b" values inside the functor (in both RIGHT and WRONG) cases, it seems they both receive correct values. The problem, I guess, says in the result returning pointer. I am updating this code in Edit 1 of the post

Comment: It's easy to compare your original 2 functors to see that this cannot be the case. In one case, the `a` and `b` values are initialized via parameter initialization, so they are the same regardless of which items are passed to the functor for a given transform call.  In the other case, the `a[idx]` and `b[idx]` values vary **element-by-element**, for each `idx` element passed to the functor.  The two cases **could not possibly be the same**.

Comment: or might it be the case that when thrust::transform is called, it initializes required N instances of "struct alter_tuple", each of them with separately initialized "int a" and "int b"? Accordingly, each thread will use those separate "a" and "b". I am not able to read and sparse Thrust code to understand which among these two cases is true but I base on the print-out which says "a" and "b" varies in each thread

Comment: this is a data race problem. However, it does not appear in alter_tupleXX functors but rather in bFunctor where paralleling thrust:transform are writing to the same "c" and "d" array. I have replaced them with local memory of bFunctor and it works perfectly. This question can also be marked as "answered". Thank you!